# Python saving to disk getting slower after every loop

Tags: python, linux, file, numpy, io

Saving through numpy.save() gets slower over 1000loops on a Linux system. What is causing this issue?

```
from time import time
import numpy as np

arr = np.ones([1080, 1920, 3], dtype=np.uint8)
path = "/tmp/testArray.{0}"

runrange = range(1000)

for i in runrange :
    t = time()
    np.save(path.format(i), arr)
    print time()-t
```

It start of taking 0.011, then up to 0.106 and ends up around 0.19

Comment: A directory is a linked list. It takes time to find a spot in the directory for a new file, and the more files are in the directory, the longer it takes.

Comment: @kindall I think you should answer it mate :).

Comment: @kindall I get the same slow down when using numpy tofile to loop through and write 1000+ arrays to a single open file. After the file gets to over 1.5gigs ish the time it takes to seek the file or write anymore arrays jumps from 0.01 to 0.12

Comment: I'm getting the same kind of problem using pickle

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old/ancient post. However, I can't reproduce problem behavior - if anything it gets slightly faster over time.

```py
from time import time

from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

arr = np.ones((1080, 1920, 3), dtype=np.uint8)
path = "testArray.{0}"
times = []

for i in range(1_000):
    t = time()
    np.save(path.format(i), arr)
    times.append((time() - t) * 1_000)

plt.figure(figsize=(9, 9))
plt.plot(range(1_000), times)
plt.savefig('time.png')
```

[image]

Tested on Win10 using `Python 3.9.1` and `numpy==1.20.1`